# Using different templates for different levels of the tree

Tags: wpf, mvvm, triggers, treeview

i want to Display a treeview bound to a Model
It works but:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" >
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubNodes}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

I want to have three Templates : one for the rootitem , a second for the subnodes and a third for subnodes but alternative to the other template.

Comment: Feel free to ask another question about the checkboxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its relatively simple.

Define three different types to which the tree is bound:

```
// defines root nodes in the tree
public sealed class RootNode : ITreeNode // or some other interface or base type
{
    public IEnumerable<SubNode> SubNodes {get;set;}
}

//  defines all middle nodes
public class SubNode : ITreeNode
{
   public IEnumerable<SubNode> Children {get;set;}
}

// defines leafs
public sealed class LeafNode : SubNode { }
```

Construct them and add them to your ViewModel

```
public sealed class ViewModel 
{
    // or use an OC<T> or whatever your design needs
    public IEnumerable<RootNode> Roots {get;set;}
```

Then use [HierarchicalDataTemplate.DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx) to designate the template for each:

```
<TreeView
  ItemsSource="{Binding Roots}">
  <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
          xmlns:t="clr-namespace:NamespaceForNodeClasses"
          DataType="{x:Type t:RootNode}
          ItemsSource="{Binding SubNodes}">
          <TextBlock Text="I'm a root node!"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
          xmlns:t="clr-namespace:NamespaceForNodeClasses"
          DataType="{x:Type t:SubNode}
          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
          <TextBlock Text="I'm a regular tree node!"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
          xmlns:t="clr-namespace:NamespaceForNodeClasses"
          DataType="{x:Type t:LeafNode}>
          <TextBlock Text="I'm a leaf!"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Hi Will, but : in MVVM the View should not know the Model. Maybe its smarter to define a BaseTreeView and Inject TreeViews defined by the ViewModel like this : Checkbox needed ? -> Inject TreeViewWithCheckboxes and so on ... what do you think of that ?

Comment: @skary "in MVVM the View should not know the Model." absolutely positively not correct.  Also, rigid orthodoxy isn't always the best course of action.  Practical and testable should be your goal.